# How can I split a discount/line item during checkout?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I have built a credit system that is working great. My original plan was to use the `onOrderComplete` event, but it turns out after testing I need to update the user's credits *before* they actually pay.

For example, A user could have one credit, but have two items in their cart. Or, have a quantity of two of any given item. Either way, the user does not have enough credits, and will have to pay for one of the items.

Here is how I am updating the user's credits:

```
// Get the user's credit entry to find out how many credits they have left.
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = craft()->config->get('section', 'myplugin');
$criteria->authorId = $user->id;
$criteria->status = null;
$criteria->limit = 1;

$entries = $criteria->find();

...

craft()->on('commerce_discounts.onBeforeMatchLineItem', function ($event) {

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ((int)$entry->qualifyingItem > 0) {
            $entry->setContentFromPost([
                'qualifyingItem' => ((int)$entry->qualifyingItem > 0) ? ((int)$entry->qualifyingItem - (int)$lineItem->qty) : 0
            ]);

            error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'CREDITS LEFT: ' . (int)$entry->qualifyingItem : '');

            if (craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)) {
                error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'SUCCESS: credits successfully updated.' : '');
            } else {
                error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'ERROR: Could not update the user\'s credits.' : '');
            }
        } else {
            $event->performAction = false;
            error_log((craft()->config->get('devMode')) ? 'Uh - oh: User is out of credits . ' : '');
        }
    }
});
```

So it seems the credits are working a bit *too* well. Either everything is "free" or the user has to pay for everything. I am having trouble figuring out how to allow one item be "free" and the other is not.

Thank you for any suggestions!